# manage messages reported as spam

Tags: http, spam-prevention

I want to have an admin page to manage user messages reported as 'spam'. I know how to use MySql and php to have a list of messages reported but I don't know what is the more safe way to access to this page. Local, https,... What strategy use big websites as Facebook, MySpace,... to verify that a message is a true spam and to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

They use spam filtering - very often implemented using [Bayesian spam filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what you're asking here:

> what is the more safe way to access to this page. Local, https,.

What's your criteria for 'safe'? What relevance does this have specifically to email analysis?

> What strategy use big websites as Facebook, MySpace,... to verify that a message is a true spam and to delete it?

There are lots of approaches - owever the problem is that providers don't publish information about how they filter spam so that the spamers can't learn to get around it.

DVK mentioned Bayesian filtering - one of the features of this is that even the people who maintain the filters don't understand how they classify a message as spam or not.

An exception to the secrecy thing is [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) - checking SPF records is a good idea.

[ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/) includes signatures for common phishing and spam messages

You might also want to have a look at [spamassassin](http://spamassassin.apache.org/) and some of the [add-on rules](http://www.rulesemporium.com/)

HTH

C.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Symcbean and DVK.
It was not what I mean but your answer is usefull.
What I mean is that on facebook every single picture, profile, message reported as a violation of the "statement of rights and responsibilities" is checked by a facebook worker. (part1...)

Comment: (part2...)
This facebook worker (I guess) has a html page where all the data reported are listed and he decides to delete them after checking that there is really a violation of facebook terms (reading the message, seing the picture, seing the profile,...). I want to have the same thing but I don't know if it is safe to put a admin password on a page were data reported are listed and add it to my website so I can access to this page everywhere. My question is "Does the facebook worker works in local or does he has access to an admin web page with password so he can works at home?"
Thanks.